# Nested GraphQL resolver not being called

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js

I have another issue with my GraphQL/Sequelize source code. It seems like my resolvers are not being used during runtime. Currently, the resolver seems to be called for the top output type (Page) but the resolver for the second output type (Content) does not seem to be called.

The query sent by the frontend:

```
query {
    pages (hidden: false) { // this resolver is called (Page)
        id
        label
        paragraphs (hidden: false) { // but not this one... (Content)
            id
            heading
            text
        }
    }
}
```

The query bundle definition:

```
import pageFields from './fields/page';
import contentFields from './fields/content';

const QueryBundle = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'This is the root query',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            pages: pageFields,
            paragraphs: contentFields
        };
    }
});
```

The pageFields file:

```
import Page from '../types/page';
import PageParagraph from '../inputs/content';
import db from '../db';

// This is the Page's fields for the QueryBundle definition...
const pageFields = {
    type: new GraphQLList(Page),
    args: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLInt
        },
        label: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        hidden: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean
        },
        paragraphs: {
            type: new GraphQLList(PageParagraph)
        }
    },
    async resolve(parent, args) {
        return await db.models.page.findAll({
            include: [{
                all: true,
                nested: true
            }],
            where: args
        });
    }
};

export default pageFields;
```

Note: This resolver will be called, both GraphiQL tool and the terminal displays a SELECT query...

The contentFields file:

```
import Content from '../types/content';
import db from '../db';

// This is the Content's fields for the QueryBundle definition...
const contentFields = {
    type: new GraphQLList(Content),
    args: {
        id: {
            type: GraphQLInt
        },
        heading: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        text: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        hidden: {
            type: GraphQLBoolean
        }
    },
    async resolve(parent, args) {
        return await db.models.content.findAll({
            include: [{
                all: true,
                nested: true
            }],
            where: args
        });
    }
};

export default contentFields;
```

Note: But this one is never called, how come? Any arguments I use in the query will be ignored as it never reaches this point...

Solution:

```
...

// This is the Sequelize model definition (output type) of the Page table...
const Page = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Page',
    description: 'This represents a Page',
    fields: () => {
        return {
            id: {
                type: GraphQLInt,
                resolve(page) {
                    return page.id;
                }
            },
            ...
            paragraphs: {
                args: {// <== This is new! Here we add the arguments...
                    hidden: {
                        type: GraphQLBoolean
                    },
                    box: {
                        type: GraphQLBoolean
                    }
                },
                type: new GraphQLList(Paragraph), // <== Unchanged
                resolve(parent, args, {pagesParagraphsLoader}, info) {// <== This is new! Here we needed a resolver for the OUTPUT type... Same goes for every nested type...
                    const data = {
                        id: parent.id,
                        args: args
                    };
                    return pagesParagraphsLoader.load(data);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});

export default Page;
```

Github with all the working changes: [goldenmaza's Github](https://github.com/goldenmaza/Aveline/tree/master/backend/schema/definitions)

Comment: This comes down to how you've implemented the resolver for the `paragraphs` fields on the `Page` type, but this is not shown in the code above.

Comment: @DanielRearden: Are you referring to the import of input type PageParagraph (inputs/content)?

Comment: This issue is now solved... Because of Daniel Rearden's comment I was able to finally find the location on where to put my resolvers (I did not know those needed resolvers as well...)... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If `pageFields` resolver with `nested:true` returns `paragraphs` then this property is already resolved.

No need to call it separately, it's resolver is skipped, not called.

This kind of resolver behaviour is used for optimalizations, overfetching in parent, when calling many child (one by one with separate DB request) would be uneffective.

Remove `nested:true` or implement additional filtering based on top level `hidden` arg (if hidden at page==hidden at paragraph). Usually complex (generated) filters build/used at top-parent query level can declare condition for nested child.

Comment: Thank you @xadm for the clarification! So if I had an argument to the nested type why is that not taken into consideration when the SELECT query is created? I am getting the nested query's response from the database almost as expected, I just get ALL of it and not filtered by query's arguments on the 2nd, 3rd etc level of nesting... Any idea as to why?

Comment: only current level resolver args can be used .... use them to construct more detailed [and more manually] `'where':` condition .... `'where sth args and paragraphs.sth2 args.hidden'`

Comment: Thank you again @xadm, I did not know that! I will now look into how I can solve this. Thx!

Comment: maybe sth like `where: {...args, paragraphs:{hidden:true} }` .... but this is sequelize related question, search docs or ask separately how to construct conditions for relations

Comment: I see what you are doing but I was hoping to use GraphQL query to determine the arguments...